# Authenticate Silverstripe users using Core PHP

Tags: php, silverstripe

My client has a website and backend made with SilverStripe. Now the client wants a mobile app and for that he wants me to build an API to communicate with the database. Unfortunately he wants me to use some other framework, or even a core PHP implementation with PDO.

#### My problem:

How does SilverStripe encrypt its password? How do I manually authenticate users using plain PHP. Only the logic to encrypt/hash (like SilverStripe does) the user input will be enough for me.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest on adding this to the ss https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-restfulserver .. Would simplify creating the middleware bit that talks between that and the app. Or just make the app use that directly. The api that talks with the api could then be created with what the client desires :)

Comment: @FinBoWa, the problem is that the client doesn't want to use silverstripe for building web service for mobile.

Comment: Yes I got that from your question, but had to suggest that as the, data is in silverstripe still? That module allows you the access to the data in xml or json format by simple requests, so it would save time quite a lot. And you can create the middleware that translates the xml/json output to the mobile app with any language you like, but you have a simple way to talk with the SS without having to create a new way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately he wants me to use some other framework, or even a core PHP implementation with PDO

You, as a developer, have the ability to tell your client why he might be wrong about this.

If the website/application is built with SilverStripe then he should have a very good/specific reason not to continue to use it to implement an API over the top of the SilverStripe data - it makes perfect sense to use SilverStripe for this, and little sense to rewrite parts of the SilverStripe framework for the sake of "not using SilverStripe."

It's also important to mention to your client that the underlying encryption/hashing algorithms that SilverStripe implements are not part of its public API, and hence can change without requiring explicit notice given to developers. This could mean that the default algorithm could be changed (for example if a zero-day exploit is found in the blowfish algorithm) and your mobile app would then stop working. Using a SilverStripe API would not have this same problem.

The above also applies to the general data structure of SilverStripe. Let's assume that one day they decide to move away from flat tables into an EAV database storage design - their public API (classes with public methods) will stay the same while their backend classes that separate the accessibility from the processing and data storage will change. *You will have to update your API too, if you build it yourself!*

> How does SilverStripe encrypt its passwords?

It depends - [the default method is encryption with the blowfish algorithm](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.4/security/Security.php#L48-L55), but there are a half dozen or so (in 3.4.1) [implementations of the `PasswordEncryptor` class](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.4/_config/encryptors.yml) that could be configured for use.

The algorithm to use is configurable via the `Security::$password_encryption_algorithm` property, or via YAML config.

Each user could have a different password encryption/hashing algorithm used - [take a look](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.4/security/Member.php#L42-L46) at the `Member` database table under the `PasswordEncryption` column.

> How do I manually authenticate users using plain PHP

Theoretically if you wanted to do this, you'd need to recreate most of the logic in the framework's authenticator. Start by looking at [`Member::checkPassword`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.4/security/Member.php#L324-L358) - this is the initiation of the logic to check the password against the member - which is what you'll care about.

You'll find yourself assuming that most implementations of SilverStripe will use the default algorithm of blowfish encryption, and follow `PasswordEncryptor::create_for_algorithm` through to [`PasswordEncryptor_Blowfish::check`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.4/security/PasswordEncryptor.php#L249). At this point you'll see that you literally will end up replicating an amount of the SilverStripe framework's code to be able to achieve what you want.

---

### Summary

- What you want to achieve will involve a lot of duplication
- It will not work for 100% of SilverStripe implementations
- It may work now, but will break at some point when the algorithms change
- Ask your client why, and convince them to change their mind about it (after all, you're the expert, they're the client)
- Use a SilverStripe API module (a couple listed below)

### API modules

- [`silverstripe/silverstripe-restfulserver`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-restfulserver) - Officially supported, and provides a simple and easy way to get started with providing API access to your SilverStripe system. You have basic control over the HTTP request methods, and can limit access and permissions by each DataObject.
- [`colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi`](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi) - Community module. Arguably more flexible and powerful. Slightly more work to set up/configure the way you want it to work.

Comment: The reason for not using Silverstripe is that, its extremely slow. There are several milllions data in the database, and when i compared silverstripe  code(written by previous programmer) with simple PDO, the code was 10 times faster. So he doesn't wants to use silverstripe. Moreover in near future he wants to recode his backend system with some other frameworks preferably phalcon or laravel.. In my case what I can do is I would call Silverstripe's login page while authenticating user instead.

Comment: If your mind is made up then it's made up, but I'd also suggest that by implementing a silverstripe API you then define a form of *interface*. Then, when/if you change your framework you just need to make sure the new API conforms to the same schema/interface as the previous, and no update to your mobile app may be required

Comment: Also re SilverStripe being slow- you have options: optimise it, or write direct DB queries into your own API controller *within the SilverStripe framework.* of course you can duplicate the logic if you want, but nobody would suggest that as best practice

Comment: I just have to point out that that with ANY given framework you can expect to get to a point when you just have to refactor some of the code to be more performant; may it be swapping some of the queries to raw ones,  tweak some original quickly done scripts to better ones, or just start throwing money on the server environment. Both of them should/could be more cost efficient than to start migrating to a new framework.